# permutations of a pin number with two selected

Tags: probability

The first part of the problem reads this:

> A pin number has 4 digits. How many arrangements, from the digits 0 to 9, are possible if a
>   number cannot be used more than once.

I can work this out correctly because there are 10 numbers and 4 numbers required:

${10!\over (10 - 4)!}$ = 5040

The second part of the question asks:

> Suppose you know 2 of the 4 numbers.  How many times could you guess
>   before arriving at the right order.  Again, using the digits 0 to 9.

The answer in the text book says

${P({4\over 2})}$ or ${4! \over (4 - 2)!}$ = 12

I don't understand why this does not take into account the numbers 0 to 9 in the solution.

Comment: It seems likely that the problem lies either in an error in the problem or in a misunderstanding or mistranslation. Can you provide a link to the problem?

Comment: It sounds as though the second part assumes that you know what the four elements are. They've given you two of the elements, but not their positions. How many combinations could you arrive at for the other two elements, taking into account the various possible positions.

Comment: Can't you just divide 10! by 6!? What do you get? And what is the difference between a number and a digit?

Comment: I've copied the question word for word.

I tried ${10! \over 6!}$ which gives 5040 so not correct.

Comment: If you really did copy this question word for word, you're learning from very bad material and should seriously considering chucking it and finding something else. It says "number" twice where it seems to mean "digit", and the entire formulation is unusual and very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for example that two of the digits are 3 and 5, then your twelve guesses as to their positions might be

```
35??, 3?5?, 3??5, 
53??, ?35?, ?3?5, 
5?3?, ?53?, ??35,
5??3, ?5?3, ??53
```

so four possibilities for the position of $3$ and three remaining possibilities for the position of $5$ or ${4 \choose 2}$. Multiply this by $8\times 7$ if you also have to guess the other two digits.